# Building a PHP Session auth flatfile - auth array

Tags: php, arrays

I am building a Session-based flatfile login auth. I have only used mysql and mysqli for this in the past so partly new.

So far, I have no errors but I need help with the array portion.

If I put static user credentials formatted in the exact same way within the array, it logs me in just fine. The way the array outputs currently from the userinfo.csv file looks correct to me but does not authenticate! Output looks like this:

```
'user@jason.com'=>'PW123',
'user2@jason.com'=>'ABC123',
```

The userinfo.csv file looks like this:

```
user@jason.com,PW123
user2@jason.com,ABC123
```

Here is the code:

```
session_start();

$handle = fopen("userinfo.csv", "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {    
    $userinfo = array("'" . $data['0'] . "'=>'" . $data['1'] ."',\r\n");
}
fclose($handle);

$errors = '';

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == ($_POST['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        header('Location:  accounts/');
    } else {
        //Invalid Login
        $errors .=  "Username or password incorrect!";
    }
}               

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = '';
    header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Notes:
I will encrypt the password once I figure out the problem with the array. Currently plain text.

I know the login process will get slower and slower as I add more users.  But there will only be 40ish users max, so this wont be an issue.

Will be implemented in an offline intranet.

I know mysqli is PERFECT for this but not my call. Sales manager wants to manage the reps with a csv file.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going through your textfile and *replacing* the variable `$userinfo` in every line.

What you actually want, is to store every entry in the array.

```
$handle = fopen("userinfo.csv", "r");
$userinfo = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {    
    $userinfo[$data[0]] = $data[1];
}
fclose($handle);
```

No need to overcomplicate it ;)

Comment: Fabian, Thank you so much.  It worked perfectly!!!

I will say a prayer for you brother, thank you so much!